# apache 2.4 php and laravel - friendly urls

Tags: php, apache, laravel

I have been pulling my hair off since the last few hours trying to get my friendly urls work. 
I have apache 2.4 with php set up. the app is built using laravel 4

so while this `http://machinename:90/helpsystem/index.php/categories` works the following does **not**  work `http://machinename:90/helpsystem/categories`

I have enabled the mod_rewrite module in apache's httpd.conf file 
Also I have added this to my alias module section of the httpd.conf

```
ScriptAlias /helpsystem "c:/Apache24/htdocs/helpsystem/public"
```

public being the the public folder of the laravel app

my directory section looks like this

```
<Directory "c:/Apache24/htdocs/helpsystem/public">
    Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

and the .htaccess file looks like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Can you please let me know what am I doing wrong ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

AllowOverride All should fix your problem, after restarting apache2

```
<Directory c:/Apache24/htdocs/helpsystem/public/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Apache's upgrade guide from 2.2 to 2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html).

Since 2.4+ is shipped out on most linux distros now (particularly Debian/Ubuntu), you'll see this crop up a lot. I  see you're on Windows, so it looks like whatever you happen to be using as updated as well! Specifically,

`Order allow,deny
Allow from all`

Has been replaced with `Require all granted` as Apache now uses [mod_authz_host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_host.html).